# Find the highest index on a string in Python

Tags: python

With function str.find(sub[, start[, end]]) it return the lowest index in the string,

```
"banana".find("a") => 1
```

how to find the highest

```
"banana".find("a") => 5
```

Answer (score 9):

A little further down in the documentation you'll find [`str.rfind()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind).